# Restarting a service using monit at random intervals

Tags: shell, scripting, monitoring, monit

I need to restart a process at random intervals using monit. Is it possible to do so? Monit takes a numeric argument in monitrc file. I want to do it at random times in a specific interval. Say, 1-5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

See the following documentation:
https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#SERVICE-POLL-TIME

You can set intervals in monit similar to cron. If it's not a service that you're monitoring, you can write a script that restarts the service and monitor that script as a program in monit (using the above service poll time).

Comment: Thanks. That was not what what I was looking for. I have been through all the official docs and couldn't find it.